# Making a bot respond with the prefix when i mention it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to be able to type "@Cool Boi prefix" and the bot will respond with what the current prefix is, for some reason it is not working, and it also shows no error message, my current code is:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('@Cool Boi prefix')
        await bot.say(' The current prefix is')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual text of the mention is slightly different from what Discord displays. One way to check if you've been mentioned is to use `bot.user.mentioned_in`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if bot.user.mentioned_in(message) and 'prefix' in message.content:
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, f'My Prefix is {bot.command_prefix}')
```

Or you could build the string using `bot.user.mention`

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(f'{bot.user.mention} prefix'):
        await bot.send_message(message.channel, f'My Prefix is {bot.command_prefix}')
```